# C++ How to Convert Pem to ASN.1

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, asn.1, ocsp

My main goal is extract ocsp response in cms signed data.

But, c++ openssl doesn't provide it.

So, I'd like to do it step by step.

1. Convert CMS signed Data(Base64) to asn.1
2. Find OCSP Response(OID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.16) in asn.1

Finally, I need some parser and finder of 1 and 2.

Base64(pem) to asn.1 parser and finder of asn.1 by OID

Is there anyone can help me or provide some useful url please?

Comment: Can you add an example of data you want to parse? Abstractly thinking you need to do (1) convert/unpack Base64. you will get DER binary data which is ASN.1 TLV data. (2) parse DER data with ASN.1 parser to get required OID node and it's value. openssl has enough power to do it.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport Thank you for reply. But, because my data is sort of confidential, so I cannot post it now. But, see According to [RFC 5652](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652): *"Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) Responses can be supported using the OtherRevocationInfoFormat."* OtherRevocationInfoFormat can store OCSP response [RFC 2560](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2560), and it is made as OCTET String.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport Fortunately, I success to get this OCTET String of OCSP response(actually, OtherRevcoationInfoFormat). But, I'm struggle with converting OCTET String to `OCSP_RESPONSE` structure.

Comment: ASN.1 is a way of describing data. DER is a binary encoding of the structured data. And PEM is an encoding of that binary encoding. And finally OCSP responses are part of many TLS implementations such as the ones by OpenSSL or (for a more C++ version) Botan. Any reason why you're not using one of the TLS libs for this? Writing BER parser is quite a bit of work, and writing an ASN.1 compiler is academic level stuff.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Cause, at least in OpenSSL I couldn't find the single api to handle the OtherRevocationInfoFormat(e.g.OCSP response), it only supports crls about Certificates RevocatioInfo.

Comment: A quick Google search shows that it even contains [a complete CLI usage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ocsp.html) for OCSP. I don't see how it can include such functionality without generating / parsing OCSP responses...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I know some parser of OCSP response in openssl from .der or .epm. But, what I mean is about parsing ocsp responses included in cms signed data(OpenSSL).  , but I'm not sure the simple api existing like `STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *CMS_get1_crls(CMS_ContentInfo *cms);` which is extracting crls at once, but case of OCSP responses, openssl doesn't support, I suppose, crls in cms related apis [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/CMS_get1_certs.html)